# Rendering of MediaWiki Infoboxes

Tags: mediawiki

I've been creating templates based on Infoboxes on my local wiki (i.e., installed MediaWiki via Bitnami) but it isn't being rendered properly. I was hoping for a infobox similar to this one I created on Wikia.

[image]

instead I got

[image]

Granted the 1st is in the monobook skin and 2nd is in vector skin, hence I would expect some discrepancy, just not this much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it looks like a simple matter of custom CSS. Wikia probably has some that your default vector skin doesn't.

Look at the classes on the generated HTML and add custom CSS for the differences (box background and border, header background, link color, font size). Then your infoboxes should appear the way you want.